# Setuptools Wheels Twine Package Install Error

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I am trying to install the package Setuptools Wheels Twine for publishing my package in Pypi but when install the setup package this error comes up. 
I am using Windows 10 as my OS and VS code.

```
    C:\Users\Farhan Hasant\moshpdf>pip install setuptools wheels twinese
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/6a/4b2fcefd2ea0868810e92d519dacac1ddc64a2e53ba9e3422c3b62b378a6/setuptools-40.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheels
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheels (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wheels
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
pip install setuptools wheel twine
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install wheels for distributing your package to PyPI.
You have to give the following commands-

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
python setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/*
```

First command will make a .whl package. Second command will make a .tar.gz package (a good practice for supporting older versions of Python) and third is the twine command which will upload your module to PyPI

Comment: How does one run `bdist_wheel` and `twine` without installing it?

Comment: Yes, you have to install twine, but I am not sure that we need to installing bdist_wheel maybe it is included with python.